# error al ejecutar java no soporta algunos paquetes

Tags: java

**tengo el siguiente problema que me da al ejecutar el programa no se si es la instalación o algo que radique o si es problema de mi código **[image: este es el error que me da]

Comment: Cuando haces `st = stringTokenizer(palabras)` ¿no debería ser `new stringTokenizer(palabras)`?

Comment: También hay un error de escritura en showInput"DI"alog seria showInputDialog con 'i' minúscula, quizás sea por eso también, ya que no deberías crear una clase llamada JOptionPane o que extienda de esta, si quieres un dialogo personalizado revisa JDialog.